# Why don't some functions work in trial versions of Mathematica?

Tags: licensing

I currently use the trial version before I decide to upgrade. However, a number of expressions don't work, i.e. it results in some errors that I don't know how to interpret. For example, if I use the simple `GeoGraphics[]` expression from the help menu, it results in the error message

```
General::unavail: ExportString is not available in this version of the Wolfram Language.
```

This error pops up in multiple contexts (e.g. other Geo-expressions, `CloudDeploy`, etc.) and I have no clue why.

Comment: It's because you have the trial version. Some features, including anything to do with exporting, are crippled in the trial version.

Comment: Duplicate, but no upvoted answer: [Mathematica 10 trial limitations](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54463/)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom There are a number of duplicates of this. I would think it makes sense to keep one question around with an answer (this one, for instance) and just close the rest as duplicates.

Comment: @acl agreed. I will retract the vote then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trial version of Mathematica doesn't allow you to export stuff.

The limitation is really there to keep people from abusing the trial.

Unfortunately, some functionality like that just doesn't work without Export.

If you want to try this functionality out:

- Try using it in the programming cloud (https://programming.wolframcloud.com/app/)
- Contact Wolfram Customer Service (http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/) and let them know that you are interested in a trying out Mathematica with export enabled.

Comment: OK thanks. I thought it was the point of a trial version to test it ...

Comment: @MockupDungeon It's a New Kind of Trial :)

Comment: The trial version has always had this type of restriction in it. But, this is the first time you can try out this stuff without even needing to install the trial.